# C++ - Do WebSockets enforce encryption, how to get "plaintext"?

Tags: c++, websocket

my friend is learning how to mess around with WebSockets on his web server so I decided to try and learn how to upgrade my HTTP/1.1 connection to WebSockets which has successfully worked! But I send data on the new websocket protocol but I retrieve information that is encrypted/compressed etc.

So my questions are

1. Is the data Encrypted/Compressed?
2. How am I able to retrieve the plaintext?
3. Are WebSockets like a TCP connection? (I know WebSockets are built on HTTP, which is built on TCP) but I know they support bi-directional streaming, so I kinda figured plaintext would be received.

Code: (This has no debugging at all because I just whipped it up quickly to connect to a WebSocket echo server that I found messing around with Fiddler)

```
    int main()
{
WSADATA WsaData = { 0 };
WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &WsaData);

addrinfo hints = { 0 }, *results = nullptr;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;

getaddrinfo("echo.websocket.org", "80", &hints, &results);

SOCKET hSocket = socket(results->ai_family, results->ai_socktype, results->ai_protocol);
connect(hSocket, results->ai_addr, static_cast<int>(results->ai_addrlen));

std::string SendBuffer;
SendBuffer = "GET http://echo.websocket.org HTTP/1.1\r\n";
SendBuffer += "Host: echo.websocket.org\r\n";
SendBuffer += "Upgrade: websocket\r\n";
SendBuffer += "Connection: Upgrade\r\n";
SendBuffer += "Origin: http://www.websocket.org\r\n";
SendBuffer += "Sec-WebSocket-Key: BBw/08+HrO3UfLPU/jeq1g==\r\n";
SendBuffer += "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\n";
SendBuffer += "Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: chat\r\n\r\n";


char RecvBuffer[1024], MessageBuffer[50];
int ReturnCode = 0;
ReturnCode = send(hSocket, SendBuffer.c_str(), SendBuffer.length(), 0);
ReturnCode = recv(hSocket, RecvBuffer, 5000, 0);

ReturnCode = send(hSocket, "Hello!", 7, 0);
ReturnCode = recv(hSocket, MessageBuffer, 50, 0);


    return 0;
}
```

WebSocket Protocol-Upgrade Reponse:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-websocket-extensions
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-websocket-version
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-websocket-protocol
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.websocket.org
Connection: Upgrade
Date: Wed, 19 Oct 2016 23:54:17 GMT
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: 6+RXVMNG1sZqeIs/Y1tlISzHAFI=
Server: Kaazing Gateway
Upgrade: websocket
```

Sending Data to WebSocket Response:

```
\x2\x3\ê
```

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455  Also "http is built on tcp" isn't true.   There is nothing about HTTP that requires TCP.

Comment: What do you mean by saying web sockets are built on http? I thought it's an independent protocol.

Comment: @Newton I was just referring to it was a layer above HTTP. (Which is what I ment but worded it poorly)

Comment: @xaxxon Nothing requires it, but as a practical matter there are no other implementations. HTTP requires a stream transport, and TCP is the only one in common use on the Internet.

Comment: One question per SO question, please.

Comment: The only thing web sockets has to do with HTTP is the handshake-once the handshake completes, it's web sockets, not HTTP. One of the primary considerations was to explicitly *avoid* HTTP overhead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please read [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455), which defines the WebSocket protocol.  In particular, [section 5: Data Framing](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5)
 and [section 6: Sending and Receiving Data](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-6).

WebSocket is NOT a plain-text protocol.  It is actually a binary protocol using framed messages, which *may* contain textual data:

> After a successful handshake, clients and servers transfer data back and forth in conceptual units referred to in this specification as "messages".  On the wire, a message is composed of one or more frames.  The WebSocket message does not necessarily correspond to a particular network layer framing, as a fragmented message may be coalesced or split by an intermediary.
>
> A frame has an associated type.  Each frame belonging to the same message contains the same type of data.  Broadly speaking, there are types for textual data (which is interpreted as UTF-8 [RFC3629] text), binary data (whose interpretation is left up to the application), and control frames (which are not intended to carry data for the application but instead for protocol-level signaling, such as to signal that the connection should be closed).  This version of the protocol defines six frame types and leaves ten reserved for future use.

Your code is not taking that into account at all.  As far as your socket code is concerned, the only plain-text portion is the initial HTTP upgrade handshake.  After the handshake is complete, you have to send and receive framed binary messages instead.  And unfortunately, the framing process is a bit complex.

Your best option is to NOT implement WebSocket manually at all, but instead use an existing WebSocket library, such as [libwebsockets](https://libwebsockets.org), [WebSocket++](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp), [easywsclient](https://github.com/dhbaird/easywsclient), etc.

Answer (score 0):

In your upgrade response, you are explicitly telling the server that you allow compression:

```
SendBuffer += "Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits\r\n\r\n";
```

If you don't want compression, remove the `permessage-deflate` extension.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE

Comment: Sorry I forgot to remove that, (I removed it but it's still not plaintxt)